# How to check it's magic method or not?

Tags: php, reflection, magic-methods

I'm try to find a check for a magic method in reflection class, but it's not there. Maybe php (I'm using php 5.3) has some other instruments to resolve this problem? Something like this:

```
class myClass {

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return 'is magic';
    }

    public function notMagic()
    {
        return 'not a magic';
    }

}


$reflection = new ReflectionMethod('myClass', 'magic');

if ($reflection->isMagic())
{
    /* do something if is magic*/
}
```

Comment: Please clarify and rephrase your question, it's unclear what you want.

Comment: i'm want to check, is callable method are magic method or not. Sorry for my english

Comment: would it be sufficient to say that if `method_exists('myClass','isMagic')` returns false it would have to get fed through your `__call()` handler?

Comment: yes, if magic like my simple examle? but if `public function __call($method, $arguments)
 {
  if ($method == 'magic')
  {
   return 'is magic';
  }
 }` is not

Comment: i want to exactly determine is callable method was described like a magic method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PHP doesn't provide a way to check if a method is magic or not you have two options.

The docs say that

> PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical.  It is
>   recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP  unless
>   you want some documented magic functionality.

You could therefore just check to see if the method name starts with `__`:

```
if(strpos($methodName, '__') === 0){
    echo "$methodName is magic";
}
```

The downside to this is that someone could make a method `__myNewMethod` and it would be considered magical despite PHP not actually doing anything with it.

Alternatively you can have a whitelist of names. Again, according to the docs, the following methods are magical:

```
__construct(), __destruct(), __call(), __callStatic(), 
__get(), __set(), __isset(), __unset(), __sleep(), 
__wakeup(), __toString(), __invoke(), __set_state() and __clone()
```

The downside of this method is that future versions of PHP may add and remove from this list making the code incorrect.

The choice would probably depend on how you want to use this info.

[PHP Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: Most people in the PHP world consider `_name` to be internal to the app, but not PHP whereas `__name` as internal to PHP. I'd personally stick to this convention and enforce it in my code.